# Unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, pch

I've been trying to organize my code into sub-folders, and I've been careful to not do anything extra than that since my last commit. I am currently getting a bunch of `C1010` errors saying:

`unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add #include "pch.h" to your source?`

Each file does have the appropriate relative include path for the precompiled header file. If I attempt to "de-relativize" the precompiled header includes, then Intellisense starts throwing errors..

I suspect that my cmake code might be at fault here..
Specifically this section:...

```
if (MSVC)
    set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT Minecraft)

    set_target_properties(Minecraft PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Yupch.h")
    set_source_files_properties("src/pch.cpp" PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Ycpch.h")

    target_compile_options(Minecraft PRIVATE "/W4" "/MP" "/std:c++17")
endif()
```

Comment: Does every `*.cpp` file start with `#include "pch.h"` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Every `.cpp` file starts with the appropriate _relative_ version of `#include "pch.h"`

Comment: When precompiled headers are enabled every source file should have `#include "pch.h"` as the first non empty non comment line

Comment: @ConnorMoody Ever file mentioned in the screen shot (please post error messages as text) does not have the `#include` the path must match the name in the compiler directive, i don't think relative paths will work.

Comment: Maybe Intellisense is confused with this: ***file starts with the appropriate relative version***

Comment: Why not use cmake's [target_precompile_headers](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/target_precompile_headers.html) instead of trying to roll your own?

Comment: @RichardCritten That is what the error messages suggest, but that is not the case. Each `.cpp` file indeed starts immediately with the appropriate relative version of `#include "pch.h"`

Comment: @spectras I suppose that is an option, I would have to learn how to implement that, but technically speaking this should be able to work regardless.

Comment: _"... relative..."_ that's the problem the directive does not match the #include

Comment: I always add the include directories via CMake and just use `#include "pch.h"`

Comment: @RichardCritten Intellisense appears to throw errors if I "de-relativize" the `pch.h` includes though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So replacing the following code...

```
if (MSVC)
    set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT Minecraft)

    set_target_properties(Minecraft PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Yupch.h")
    set_source_files_properties("src/pch.cpp" PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Ycpch.h")

    target_compile_options(Minecraft PRIVATE "/W4" "/MP" "/std:c++17")
endif()
```

with

```
if (MSVC)
    set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT Minecraft)

    target_precompile_headers(Minecraft PRIVATE "src/pch.h")

    target_compile_options(Minecraft PRIVATE "/W4" "/MP" "/std:c++17")
endif()
```

solved the issue!